# Bubble Sorting a Matrix in Java by Ascending and Descending order

Tags: java, bubble-sort

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ROW = 10;
        int COLUMN = 2;
        final int RANK = 0;
        final int COST = 1;
        double[][] Example = {
                {2, 5.60},{6, 76.00},{1,2.30},{4,22.00},{7,13.40},{5,102.00}
                ,{10,34.00},{9,9.99},{3,1.00},{8,15.00};
    double[] tempData;
    int swapCounter = 1;
    int comparisons = (Example.length);



    for (int zz = 0; (zz < Example.length) && (swapCounter > 0) ; zz++)
    {
        swapCounter = 0;
        comparisons--;
        //comparisons
        for (int index = 0; index < comparisons ; index++)
        {

            if (Example[index][COST] < Example[index+1][COST] &&
                    (Example[index][RANK] > Example[index+1][RANK]
                    || Example[index][RANK] == Example[index+1][RANK]))
            {
                // Sorting Matrix
                tempData = Exmaple[index];
                Example[index] = Example[index+1]; 
                EXample[index+1] = tempData;


                swapCounter++;
            }
       }
   }
```

How would I bubble sort this matrix to have the RANK(integers) in ascending order and order the COST(floating pt integers) be ordered in descending at the same time.

My goal is to print out a table of these elements, rank in ascending order and cost in descending.

No need for help printing, just sorting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks very much like a homework dump.

Comment: By implementing the Bubble Sort algorithm.

Comment: why the bubble sort?

Comment: @MauricePerry likely 'cause homework. It is often a starting point in complexity analysis.

Comment: @micahclarke if you make your question more "I have a bubble sort impl, below, and it works to sort XXXX. How can I sort the following 2D array?" then it will likely get more attention. Currently this question looks like you are asking us to implement a bubble sort for you.

Comment: I'm most familiar with bubble sort so I was wondering if I could order two different columns two different way. @MauricePerry.

Comment: Furthermore, in Java, variables are **always** in `camelCase`. No excuses. No Exceptions. _Especially_ when you post code on public forums and asking for input.

Comment: @MauricePerry I apologize I worded my question and typed my code that doesn't suit your liking. If you have an answer I would certainly appreciate it. If you don't have any desire to help then no worries. Have a good day.

Comment: How can you sort both by cost and by rank?

Comment: I know how to sort by cost and rank if both are being sorted by descending order only or both are being sorted by ascending order only. Just don't know how to sort one ascending and the other descending.

Answer (score 0):

Your test looks wierd:

```
        if (Example[index][COST] < Example[index+1][COST] &&
                (Example[index][RANK] > Example[index+1][RANK]
                || Example[index][RANK] == Example[index+1][RANK]))
```

It is equivalent to:

```
        if (Example[index][COST] < Example[index+1][COST] &&
                Example[index][RANK] >= Example[index+1][RANK])
```

But perhaps you meant:

```
        if (Example[index][RANK] > Example[index+1][RANK]
                || Example[index][RANK] == Example[index+1][RANK]
                && Example[index][COST] < Example[index+1][COST])
```